# MySites - Changing Organization to Organisation

Tags: my-site

I've noticed a couple of people with a similar problem, but I am not aware of a solution.

In My Sites, even though I have the regional location as UK - the spelling of Organisation is the Americanised Organization. Several users have asked me to change this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

You can change title of the tab in the quick launch.  Open <my_site_url>/_layouts/quiklnch.aspx page or go "Site Actions"->"Site Settings"->"Look and Feel"->"Quick Launch". You need have permissions for edit site settings on the My Site host. And than edit "Organization" heading link description.